# Is there an analytical solution (or approximation) to the logarithm of the cumulative normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

At some point in my calculations I have come up with $\ln(1 + \textrm{erf}(x))$ and I cannot simplify it any further. Is there a way? Any approximation with some specified error $\mathcal{O}(f(x))$ would help me a lot.

Comment: You want an approximation of $\log(1+\text{erf}(x))$ for $x$ tending to what? For $x\to +\infty$ the error function converges really fast to $1$, hence for $x\to +\infty$ your function converges really fast to $\log 2$.

Comment: I meant an approximation in the sense that I don't need an exact formula for (1+erf(x)) (some degree of error is acceptable); but I need to be able to compute (1+erf(x)) for specific values of x, not at the limit

Answer (score 0):

Abramowitz and Stegun, formulas 26.2.12 thru 26.2.15 might help.